# $M$ finitely generated over $(R,\mathfrak{m})\Rightarrow M/\mathfrak{m}M$ artinian

Tags: commutative-algebra, artinian

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m},k)$ be a commutative noetherian local ring and let $M$ be a finitely generated module over $R$.

Is $M/\mathfrak{m}M$ artinian? Since $M/\mathfrak{m}M$ is noetherian it is enough to show that it has finite length but I am not able to see it. Can someone help (if it's true)?

Comment: Have you considered the fact that $M/\mathfrak{m}M$ is an $R/\mathfrak{m}$-module? It is also finitely generated as such. What fact about $R/\mathfrak{m}$ could help you out?

Comment: @Chris Leary Yes it is a vector-space over $R/\mathfrak{m}$ since $R/\mathfrak{m}$ is a field. As a field $R/\mathfrak{m}$ is artinian and since $M/\mathfrak{m}M$ is fin. gen. over $R/\mathfrak{m}$ it is artinian as a $R/\mathfrak{m}$-vector space. But why does it follow that it is also artinian as $R$-module?

Comment: The submodules of $M/\mathfrak{m}M$ are the same whether it is considered as an $R$-module or as an $R/\mathfrak{m}$-module. This information is Theorem 1.13 of Sharpe and Vamos, "Injective Modules." The theorem is an example of a change of rings theorem. I haven't seen it anywhere else that I can think of, although I'm sure it must be in many references.